# What does a windows login really do?

Tags: windows, windows-7

So I really don't feel comfortable posting the exact details just yet, and obviously its still in the works so i'll just tell you the problem. I've gotten windows (Windows 7) to open a variety of different Programs while still at the login screen (I.e. no user is logged in yet), such as cmd.exe, taskmgr.exe, and explorer.exe all with full Administrator rights. I'm curious what exactly logging in does, because any complex programs I try to execute will open, however they will not run properly or open other programs. for example: After I open explorer.exe and it boots the desktop, navigating to a program through explorer will not open the program correctly, and it will sometimes complain about incorrect user (which kinda makes sense). Programs like chrome will pretty much act like a fancy clickable window that does nothing. you can edit settings and such but it is always gray instead of displaying a webpage. I can still open a Program manually (or using taskmanager or cmd) but anyways I am hoping someone can explain to my the following to me (there are many gaps in my knowledge of windows):
1.) what is the difference between programs and processes?
2.) what programs/processes are executed when a windows user logs in?
3.) what processes are responsible for the login screen itself? (If closed through taskmanager or cmd, the login screen application reopens almost immediately)
4.) does windows verify a user account everytime a program/processes is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how to answer all those questions, but you could use some knowledge about what is exactly a user interface and an OS.

An excellent read and very understandable is this text :

http://patrickgoudjoako.com/2013/08/18/a-text-every-software-engineer-should-skim-or-even-read/

It is long but well written and useful to understand a great part of the computers history and present.